# Making types created in C# accessible from vba using VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I'm using VSTO to make a bunch of functions written in C# accessible from Excel VBA.  It would be convenient to create types (say, a class) with a number of properties to allow me to pass that single class to and from excel.

VSTO overrides the RequestComAddInAutomationService method to expose a single class which contains the methods I want to expose.  I therefore cannot figure out how to expose a second class or struct etc.   My class uses an interface to expose its methods to vba, but you cannot define types in an interface.  I have tried to create the type class within my main class, but am unable to get vba to recognise it.

This is the code inside "ThisAddIn.cs:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
  private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
  }

  private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
  }

  #region VSTO generated code

  /// <summary>
  /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
  /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
  /// </summary>
  private void InternalStartup()
  {
    this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
    this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
  }

  #endregion

  private AddInUtilities utilities;

  protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
  {
    if (utilities == null) utilities = new AddInUtilities();

    return utilities;
  }
}
```

And in AddInUtilities.cs:

[ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IAddInUtilities
    {
      string[] ListKeyMetrics();
      string[]  ListSetptMetrics();
      AddInUtilities.testStruct myTest();
      double test { get; set; }
    }

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class AddInUtilities : IAddInUtilities
{
  public class testStruct
  {
    private double _x;
    private double _y;

    public testStruct(int z)
    {
      _x = 0;
      _y = 0;
    }

    public double x
    {
      get { return _x; }
      set { _x = value; }
    }

    public double y
    {
      get { return _y; }
      set { _y = value; }
    }
  }

  public double test
  {
    get; set;

  } = 5;

  public string[] ListKeyMetrics()
  {
    string[] ret = { "SCz", "SCx", "etc" };
    return ret;
  }

  public string[] ListSetptMetrics()
  {
    string[] ret = { "FRH", "RRH", "etc" };
    return ret;

  }

  public testStruct myTest()
  {
    testStruct ret = new testStruct(0);
    ret.x = 1;
    ret.y = 2;
    return ret;
  }

}
```

Any suggestions on how I can create a type in VSTO and have it visible from vba?

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162601/intellisense-in-custom-com-classes-in-vba

Comment: FWIW, I would add that I'm not seeing a reason why you need VSTO here. This can be done with just a plain C# DLL referenced in VBA project, as @Vityata linked to. Normally, you use VSTO because you want to customize the host, expose some custom functionality on the Office host or something like that. But for a bunch of functions? VSTO is just making it more complicated for you. COM Interop is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VSTO here. Since you intend to run your functions from VBA, you do not need to run your build to communicate with Excel, but only with VBA and when it needs it.

So best would be to create a Class Library project (DLL), which you can then reference from VBA.

- How to reference:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference
- How to interface with VBA (it's for C++ but the principle is the
  same): https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781119206149.app4